# Difficult text recognition using tesseract

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, crop, tesseract

Some text images are not recognized by tesseract.

FOr example consider the following `rails` image which is not recognized by tesseract

[image]

The above image when OCRed, gives no output.

And some images accuracy is not upto the mark.

I am using ruby on rails and to implement tesseract OCR text recognition I am using 'gem tesseract' and some code. 
What's the problem and how do I get the output with nice accuracy.

Comment: did you try to use ocr through docsplit?

Comment: Is it only for pdf documents? I want to use OCR for images only.

Comment: Did you try it on a basic black and white images with text only to make sure tesseract is working?

Comment: I experience the same. Did you find any solutions, ideas, alternatives or workarounds? I was really imressed that tesseract worked right out of the box, but I need it to be more robust and to grab all clearly visible text despite distractions in the images.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Tesseract is meant for images with only text. Results for images like the one you have posted are not guaranteed.

You will need to do some image processing (crop the image to only the text part), and convert the image to black-text-on-white-background.

Comment: I forgot to tell that I already had cropped the image to the text part and after that got the blank output. I think that black-text-on-white-background should work. Is it possible to trace the text, change its color to black and background to white using ImageMagick?

Comment: For this single case - yes, but if you want to do it for a series of images, you'll need a more involved approach.

Comment: Applied convert to this image in order to get the white background as `convert /paperclip_cropper/app/assets/images/rails.png -background white -extent 495X320 -gravity center output.jpg` with no output. That is the same image returned with no change. :(